# How to update variable in parent function inside AJAX WITHOUT ASYNC FALSE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

AJAX is async by default and as of jquery 1.8, setting async: false is deprecated. I do not wish to break asynchronous property of AJAX anyway. Most of answers I found on here say to set async false. So what is a better way to do it? I would like to update count after all the loops are done.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "...", 
  success: function (objects) {
    var count = 0; 

    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) { 
      logObject(object[i], count); // update count in every loop
    }

    console.log(count); // ALWAYS 0
  }
});

function logObject(object, count) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "...", 
    success: function (result) {
      console.log(object.item); // works fine
      count+=result.count; // count increases everytime unless result.count is 0
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: a new way to do this would be to use promises, like `$.when` but i never did it in a loop with a dynamic number of promises. The old way to do this is to use callbacks, for example, each finished `logObject` can increment a variable (from a upper scope, so that each one uses the same var) and compare it to the number of responses you expect. when all is done you can go to final step, which can be a dynamic function instead of fixed operations, if you like.

Comment: I did use callbacks before and have logObject increment variables but since AJAX is async, the variables get updated all over the page with no real good order

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to increment a counter on start and reduce when done, like this:

```
var activeAjaxConnections = 0;

.ajax({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    activeAjaxConnections++;
  },
  success: function(resp) {
    activeAjaxConnections--;
     if (activeAjaxConnections === 0) {
        // done.....
     }
  },
  error: function(xhr, errDesc, exception) {
    activeAjaxConnections--;
  }
});
```

Or - more global - you play around with: [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

Comment: Why is there a `activeAjaxConnections--;` inside success function

Comment: Also please see edit, count should be incremented at every loop. I made mistake, should be `count += result.count`

Comment: I increment the counter each time a request starts, and on each response (error or success) I decrement it again. In the second the the connection is 0 - all open requests are done. Might be that I misinterpret your question - to be honest I have no idea why you log an object via ajax which you just received by ajax. I thought your goal is to update your counter when all requests are done - well, the code above could do that.

Comment: I have to log it inside another function because in the parent ajax, I loop through objects, if I do not do it in a separate function and pass in object, the child ajax and its children will not be able to see object[i].item

Answer (score 0):

First of all you pass `"count"` parameter to function and update it inside this function. It never works because `"count"` is a primitive type, is integer, and inside your function `"logObject"` you will work with the copy of `"count"` is passed by value.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "...", 
  success: function (objects) {
    var count = 0; 

    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) { 
      logObject(object[i]).success(function(result){
          count += result.count; 

          if((i + 1) === objects.length){
              //Here you finished the loop
              console.log(count);
          }
      }); // update count in every loop
    }
  }
});

function logObject(object) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "..."
  });
}
```

Comment: I do not understand where is count updated to result.count in this code?

Comment: in this example count is not updated, because inside success function of Promise.all i know that all calls to logObject was succeeded... So you count is just number of objects

Comment: No please see question, edited 25 mins ago, `count+=result.count`, it's not just the length of objects, it is dynamic because result.count could be different everytime

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: This would work but is there anyway to make logObject() execute in order from `i = 0` to  `objects.length` because since it's an AJAX call it will not preserve the order